# Customizing Swagger-UI Layout

Tags: reactjs, swagger, swagger-ui

[Swagger-UI docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/custom-layout/) shows an example of customizing the layout by using `getComponent("operations")`. [This is in the list of components](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/src/core/components/) that Swagger-UI uses. This works fine in React. However, it won't work with other components. For example, if wanted to get the "operation" component, how would I include it?

I've tried using `getComponent("operation")` to no success. I saw that there are default props. Do I need to supply those to the component? If so, how would supply them? In the component [Operation.jsx](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/operation.jsx), one of the props is called `operation` (please see below). My OpenAPI 3.0 file has `operationID` which did not work.

Here is where I am trying to get the `operation` component:

```
    render() {
        const {getComponent} = this.props;
        const Operations = getComponent("operations", true);
        const Operation = getComponent("operation", true);
        return (
            <div>
               //this works (from the example) 
               <Operations/>

               //this does not work 
               <Operation/>
            </div>
        )
```

These are the default props:

```
static defaultProps = {
    operation: null,
    response: null,
    request: null,
    specPath: List(),
    summary: ""
  }
```

I expected to see `getComponent(<any component>)` be rendered, but the actual output is: 
`AppContainer, in SwaggerComponent (at pages/index.js:18)) TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'y.toJS')`

Comment: Post complete component code.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: You got it working??

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023, I still can't show custom layout base on the documentation given.

I'd look into css to hide some of the layouts.

Wrapped the whole `SwaggerUI` in div element and target the class of block you want to remove by putting `display: none`.

Example:
To hide operation block, you can do something like this

```
.swagger-main .opblock-section-request-body {
  display: none;
}
```